# Send PUT Request to CoRE Resource Directory using CoAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, coap

I want to generate PUT request. I have successfully generated GET request to get data from CoRE resource directory but I am unable to generate PUT request with xml payload. Your help would be highly appreciated.
Following is my code

```
    function PutReq(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    var request2 = new CoAPRequest(); 
    var payload  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><te:lightingSceneRootType xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"xmlns:te="http://www.baas-itea3.eu/temperature"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><lightingSceneName>Off</lightingSceneName></te:lightingSceneRootType>';
      alert(payload);
      request2.open('PUT', wLink , true);   
      request2.onload = function () {
      var res2 = request2.responseText; 
      alert(res2);  
      };
      request2.send(); 
      }, 2000);
      }
```

wLink is the variable in which I have put the url. I am using this delay function because I am taking the link from the first function and I need to run this request with delay so that I can get the response from first function. 
The problem is, how to send payload using put request. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Umar, can you help me please? Can you tell me how you implemented CoRE resource directory?

Answer (score 1):

i *think* you just need to pass `payload` to `send`

`request2.send(payload);`

Comment: I think this too. but I should get some message in response. At this time I am not able to get any response message eg: changed. In copper for firefox plugin. I am getting changed response but using this code I am not able to do this.